# Field strength renormalization: going outside of Fock space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

When one talks about field strength renormalization, one defines the renormalized field $\psi^R(x)$ in the following way (I'm using the notation from Matthew Schwartz's book): $\psi^R(x) \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{Z_2}} \psi^0$, where $\psi^0$ is the bare free field (an operator acting on the usual Fock space) and $Z_2$ is some **formally infinite** number.

Now, even though it is the Green's function of the renormalized fields that should have finite physical values, should we be worried that such a definition takes us outside of Fock space? Are we changing the operators' amplitudes by making such a definition?

Comment: What do you mean by "taking us outside of Fock space"? An interacting theory, strictly speaking, doesn't have a Fock space as its space of states to begin with - we're always in the asymptotic free field case when talking about Fock spaces in QFT.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I'm not talkng about interacting theory yet. $\psi^0$ is the **free** field.

Comment: Why would you worry about field strength renormalization for a free field?

Comment: @higgsss, it's defined for the FREE field as above.

Comment: We define $\psi^{R}$ to deal with interaction effects. For a free theory, $Z_{2}=1$, and $\psi^{R} = \psi^{0}$.

Comment: @higgsss, again, $\psi^0$ is an operator (well, operator-valued distrb) acting on Fock space, which is the direct sum of the vacuum, 1-part states, 2-particle states and so on, correct? Now, you take this operator and divide it by some devilish constant that could be infinite. What I'm asking is, first, will it take us outside of Fock space, on which $\psi^0$ acts, and second, can this redefinition be interpreted as the change of amplitudes of operators in the Fourier decomposition of $\psi^0$.

Comment: Where did you find field-strength renormazation defined for a free field? Schwartz's book certainly introduces this concept for interacting fields. For free fields, nothing renormalizes the paramters in the theory. Even if you introduce $\psi^{R} = \psi^{0}/\sqrt{Z_2}$, it is a mere redefinitionof your field variable.

Comment: As ACuriousMind pointed out, the Hilbert space of an interacting field theory, to be strict, is not a Fock space. I don't really know anything about this in detail, but you might want to look into literature on non-Fock spaces or rigorous formulation of the $\phi^{4}$ theory in two or three spacetime dimensions.

Comment: @higgsss is correct - the field strength renormalization is $1$ if and only if the theory is free, so your question dissolves either way: Either you don't have to renormalize at all, or you don't have a Fock space. I don't know what you're asking.